# Issue with Google Translate and jShowOff

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, google-translate

I have been asked to look in to a issue that has occured on a website that is using both the Google Website Translator and the JQuery plugin jShowOff, a slideshow type plugin (both great features).

The website is http://www.nic.coop and when you select another language to translate the website in to, it translates everything on screen, as exspected.  However when the jShowOff changes its current slide this slide is not now translated.

I think the reason for this is that the Google Website Translator script only runs once and then only translates visible elements, after all why translate elements that are not visible! :) If this is the case does anybody know if it is possible for a bit of jQuery that will kick the Google translator to re translate part of the page when the jShowOff script changes and elements visibility?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get the jShowOff plug in to do this, shouts out to the author of the plugin who contacted me offline to try and help.
I will be using the jquery.cycle plugin as this allows the Google Website Translator to work with the slides.